# About functions

Tags: function, numbers, return

In the code below I try to find prime numbers. My problem is that, I am not sure how to use print inside a function.

Is it correct? I get an answer but it both says 6 is not a prime number and it also gives "None". How can I get rid of this "None"? Also, is it okay to use `return` just like this?

```
#Prime number

def prime(num):
    for i in range (2,num):
        if num%i == 0:
            print num, "is not a prime number."
            return 
        else:
            print num, "is a prime number."
            return 

print prime(6)
```

Comment: This is python right? If yes please make an edit to add that tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have print statements in your code already so just calling `prime` will result in stuff being printed to the screen. When you have a bare `return` your function will return `None`. That means that when you do:

```
print prime(6)
```

`prime(6)` will return `None` which makes this equivalent to:

```
print None
```

Then you have a major logic error in your code because you do not check every possible divisor due to `return`ing too early. For example if you have the number be 9, this is not a prime number. However your function will print that it is a prime because on the first run through the for loop `i` will be 2 which means `9%2` is false so the else branch gets taken and it prints out that the number is prime. The function then returns at that point without checking the rest of the numbers. If you run this code you will see what happens: http://ideone.com/zxdez2

The design issue here is that you really should keep IO separate from the rest of the functionality. Say you wanted to reuse `prime` somewhere else later on you can't do this without also having that code print out to the screen. This might not be what you want at that later date but it's hard to do something with that. Instead it is much cleaner to return a boolean that represents if the number was prime or not *then* print out based on that returned value:

```
def prime(num):
    for i in range (2,num):
        if num%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

x = 6
if prime(x):
    print x, "is not a prime number."
else:
    print x, "is a prime number."
```